# PHP preg_match word + wildcard

Tags: php, preg-match-all

I'm trying to get values like these `color="#7fff00"`, `color="#bfffff"`, etc from file using preg_match_all:

```
preg_match_all( '/\bcolor=([a-f ]*)/', $data, $mc);
```

but all I get is `color=` and thats all.. I'm not sure Im doing it right.. Probably not.. Can anyone explain to me how to search for word COLOR=   and everything that follows after that word? Thnaks

Comment: You are missing the `"` and `#` characters. But a regex might not be the best way, what are you trying to parse, html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not matching the quotes or `#` character in the string. Change your pattern to:

```
preg_match_all('/\bcolor="([#a-f]*)"/i', $data, $mc);
```

But depending on what you're trying to parse, a regex might not be the best tool. If you're trying to parse HTML, it's always best to use an HTML parser.

Comment: @user3065540: Glad to have been of help. Cheers!